# Difference between chomp and trim in Perl?

Tags: perl, trim, chomp

What is the difference between `chomp` and `trim` in Perl? Which one is better to use and when?

Comment: There is no trim function in Perl. Which module are you talking about?

Answer (score 5):

**Chomp:** The `chomp()` function will remove (usually) any newline character from the end of a string. The reason we say usually is that it actually removes any character that matches the current value of `$/` (the input record separator), and `$/` defaults to a newline.
For more information see [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html).

As *rightfold* has commented *There is no trim function in Perl.* Generally people write a function with name *trim* (you can use any other name also) to remove leading and trailing white spaces (or single or double quotes or any other special character)

**trim** remove white space from both ends of a string:

```
$str =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
```

Answer (score 1):

trim removes both leading and trailing whitespaces, chomp removes only trailing input record separator (usually new line character).

Comment: trim is not in core module it is in [String::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Util)

Answer (score 0):

Chomp: It only removes the last character, if it is a newline.

More details can be found at: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html

Trim: There is no function called Trim in Perl. Although, we can create our function to remove the leading and trailing spaces in Perl. Code can be as follows:

**perl trim function - remove leading and trailing whitespace**

```
sub trim($)
{
  my $string = shift;
  $string =~ s/^\s+//;
  $string =~ s/\s+$//;
  return $string;
}
```

More details can be found at :http://perlmaven.com/trim

Comment: Haha I wrote something almost exactly like this a few years ago to trim leading/trailing whitespace. For completeness I also put a `chomp $string;` near the top too :)

Comment: Pedantically, `chomp` doesn't remove a newline, it removes the current value of `$/` (which is usually a newline).